# Non associative aggregations in apache spark streaming

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to build a utility layer in Java over apache spark streaming where users are able to aggregate data over a period of time (using window functions in spark) but it seems all the available options require associative functions (taking two arguments). However for some fairly common use cases like averaging temperature sensor values over an hour, etc. dont seem possible with the spark API.

Is there any alternative for achieving this kind of functionality? I am thinking of implementing repetitive interactive queries to achieve that, but it will be too slow.

Comment: avg = sum/count where sum and count are associative.  Associativity gives you the ability to parallelize operations. You need that in a parallel, distributed framework as Spark. What are the cases you are considering?

Comment: Our use case is to have an automated alert system where we send out emails if average sensor data (over an hour) crosses a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical aggregates (average, variance) are actually associative and can be computed online. See [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) for a good numerical way of doing this.

In terms of number of arguments, remember the type of what you put in arguments is of your choice. You can nest several arguments in one of these using a Tuple.

Finally, you can also use stateful information with something like [updateStateByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html).